# BMP transformation seg fault - alloc or something else

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bmp

can someone help me with my code? I was looking at it for like half a day and still cant find any seg fault... I think problem is somewhere where i allocate memory bcs i really dont understand what am i doing :D.

```
struct bmp_image* flip_horizontally(const struct bmp_image* image){
if(image == NULL || image->data == NULL || image->header == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
struct bmp_image* new_image= calloc(1,sizeof(struct bmp_image));
new_image->header = calloc(1,sizeof(struct bmp_header));
new_image->header =image->header;

uint32_t height=image->header->height, width=image->header->width;

struct pixel* pixels = calloc(height*width,sizeof(struct pixel));
for (uint32_t y = 0; y<height; y++){
    for(uint32_t z = 0, zz = width-1; z<width; z++, zz--){
        pixels[(y*width)+zz]=image->data[(y*width)+z];
    }   
}
new_image->data=pixels;

return new_image;}
```

```
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (1/4/8/24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));

struct pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
    //uint8_t alpha;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

struct bmp_image {
    struct bmp_header* header;
    struct pixel* data;         // nr. of pixels is `width` * `height`
};
```

Comment: `new_image->header =image->header;` something odd?

Comment: Also try to get a core dump and backtrace.

Comment: probably should be `*(new_image->header) = *(image->header)`, or use memcpy

Comment: since you're using a sane compiler, you might also try `-fsanitize=undefined` and/or valgrind.

Comment: You're not accounting for padding each row to a multiple of 4 bytes. May not matter if this is only being used by your code, but it will if the data comes from or is given to with functions or a library that expects correctly formed BMP data and your width is not one that would not require additional padding.

Comment: Where do you get the segfault?